# SQL 2008 FILESTREAM - How to Check if DB Has Filestream Enabled Before Altering It

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In my situation, there is a possibility of a script being run many times (don't ask why).

So I want to make my script bullet proof before it runs in prod.

I have a pretty big change where I add FILESTREAM capabilities.  I have already got it to work in my dev environment with the necessary scripts by enabling FILESTREAM, altering the database to add a filestream file group, and then adding a file location to that file group, and lastly creating a table with filestream on the data column (varbinary(MAX)).

That is all good.  But running the ALTER DATABASE script many times can produce errors if a file group is already there.  So i did this...

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.filegroups WHERE [name]='NewFileGroup')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [MyDb]
        ADD FILEGROUP [NewFileGroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM
    END 
GO
```

But the next part of the code is the part that i don't want running many times...

```
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Path = (SELECT REPLACE(filename, 'MyDb.mdf', 'NewFileGroup') FROM sysfiles WHERE Name = 'PrimaryFileName')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = 
'ALTER DATABASE [MyDb]
ADD FILE
  (NAME = ''NewFileGroup''
   , FILENAME = ' + QuoteName( @Path, '''' ) 
            + ')
TO FILEGROUP [NewFileGroup]'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

That code works fine but how do i check if the FILENAME / file path already exists in that file group? Please someobody help. I just want to make another if statement around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if you have already a filegroup for FILESTREAM look in [`sys.data_spaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190289.aspx):

```
select * from sys.data_spaces where type='FD';
```

To see if the filegroup has any file for FILESTREAM already look is [`sys.database_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397.aspx):

```
select * from sys.database_files where type = 2;
```

Whatever you do, do **not** rely on the object *names*.

Comment: Why not rely on the names if I am defining them?

Comment: If you're not sure that the filegroups are there or not, then how can you be sure that the database is enabled for filestream or not? DBA adds a filegroup enabled for filstream named foo, your applicaiton comes along and tries to add its own...

Comment: Im making all the scripts that another team (my IT department) will be running on the database....sometimes they run them out of order and/or run them multiple times... i am just trying to put checks in to make sure errors arent displayed all over the place

Answer (score 1):

Or from SQL Server 2012 and above this query will list all the databases which have non-transactional access enabled on them, i.e, FileStream.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) [DB_Name],directory_name [FileStream_DirectoryName]
    FROM  sys.database_filestream_options
    WHERE non_transacted_access != 0;
```

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492071.aspx for more info